# Collection initialization syntax in Visual Basic 2008?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, collections, initialization

I'm trying to determine if there's a way in Visual Basic 2008 (Express edition if that matters) to do inline collection initialization, a la JavaScript or Python:

```
Dim oMapping As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = {{1,"First"}, {2, "Second"}}
```

I know Visual Basic 2008 supports array initialization like this, but I can't seem to get it to work for collections... Do I have the syntax wrong, or is it just not implemented?

Comment: For future searchers, two solutions are provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629076/inline-list-initialization-in-vb-net

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Visual Basic 9.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET#Visual_Basic_2008_.28VB_9.0.29) doesn't support this yet. However, [Visual Basic 10.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET#Visual_Basic_2010_.28VB_10.0.29) [will](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx).

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Here are [VB collection initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) using the **From** keyword. (Starting with Visual Studio 2010)

**List:**

```
Dim list As New List(Of String) From {"First", "Second"}
```

**Dictionary:**

```
Dim oMapping As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From {{1, "First"}, {2, "Second"}}
```

Comment: Is this only for VB.NET version 10 and later? Corresponding to which version of Visual Studio?