# Why are array initializers only allowed for arrays?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Collection initialization syntax in Visual Basic 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85892/collection-initialization-syntax-in-visual-basic-2008)

This does not compile.

```
Dim Tom As New List(Of String) = {"Tom", "Tom2"}
```

This does

```
Dim Tom As String() = {"Tom", "Tom2"}
```

IMO this features should be allowed for all collection types and not only arrays.

Comment: Can't be done in VB.NET. C# does have 'var k = new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};' but there's no direct equivalent in VB.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this in the current version of Visual Basic, but the next version in Visual Studio 2010 allows this syntax:

```
Dim Tom As List(Of String) = new List(Of String) From {"Tom", "Tom2"}
```

It uses the [new *From* keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617(VS.100).aspx).

C#, on the other hand, has included its collection initializer syntax in Visual Studio 2008. You can read about it *[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)* (MSDN).

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft agrees with you.  It is supported starting in the next release of VB, VB 2010.  See this question: [Collection initialization syntax in VB 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85892/collection-initialization-syntax-in-vb-2008).

MSDN: [What's New in Visual Basic 2010?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we86c8x2%28VS.100%29.aspx)