# Inline list initialization in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Collection initialization syntax in Visual Basic 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85892/collection-initialization-syntax-in-visual-basic-2008)

How is the following C# code translated to VB.NET?

```
var theVar = new List<string>{"one", "two", "three"};
```

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Use this syntax for [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) 2005/2008 compatibility:

```
Dim theVar As New List(Of String)(New String() {"one", "two", "three"})
```

Although the [VB.NET 2010 syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629076/inline-list-initialization/2629119#2629119) is prettier.

Comment: This is not the same.  (It creates an array and calls a constructor overload)

Comment: Not the same, but the best option until you get VB.Net 2010

Comment: Hmm, the <2010 syntax doesn't really offer any added value over just splitting it over two lines. It is the answer to my question though. Thx

Answer (score 257):

Collection initializers are [only available in VB.NET 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336123.aspx), released 2010-04-12:

```
Dim theVar = New List(Of String) From { "one", "two", "three" }
```

Comment: Better to use `Dim theVar As New List....` otherwise `theVar` is assumed to be an `Object` and intelisense won't give you the methods/properties/etc, and you will get compiler warnings (although it will still compile anyway)

Comment: @freefaller: With `Option Infer`, you don't need to.