# From Clause in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I just found the following snippet:

```
Return New List(of obj) From { _ 
New obj With {.a = 1, .b = 2, 
New obj With {.a = 3, .b = 4}
```

I thought... ok, why using `From` here? I know `From` from Linq but havent seen it in a situation as above. So I checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384802.aspx):

> Specifies one or more range variables and a collection to query.

I get that connected to a Linq query like `From X in Y` where `X` is a variable in a collection `Y` but I dont understand it in the context above. Could anyone explain to me what From means in the snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not `LINQ` although they share the `From` keyword. This is called [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) or sometimes [inline list initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629076/inline-list-initialization-in-vb-net).

> *"Collection initializers provide a shortened syntax that enables you to create a collection and populate it with an initial set of values. Collection initializers are useful when you are creating a collection from a set of known values, for example, a list of menu options or categories, an initial set of numeric values, a static list of strings such as day or month names, or geographic locations such as a list of states that is used for validation." - MSDN -*

Comment: Ah, I checked the Tooltip of 'from' got From Clause and googeled it and got on the wrong way. Thanks for getting me back on the right path, your information is very helpful to me!