# Inline initialization of a List(Of MyClass)

Tags: vb.net

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629076/inline-list-initialization-in-vb-net) a question was asked about inline initializing a list of strings in vb.net. I have a list of a class i created in VS 2013 (it just contains 2 properties, ID as Integer, Name as string). Is there a way to inline-initialize it to some default values?

I tried

```
Dim _products As New List(Of Product) From {{ID = 1, Name = "Product 1"}}
```

but no luck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. You created the list (`New List(Of Product)`), but you also need to create the objects themselves (`New Product`):

```
Dim _products As New List(Of Product) From {
    New Product With {.ID = 1, .Name = "Product 1"},
    New Product With {.ID = 2, .Name = "Product 2"},
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just missing the `Dot` notation for the properties. `{.ID = 1, ...`

Comment: you may define an [`Add` extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57636993/2803565) to simplify this task greately!