# Simplify List initialisation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list

What are the options to simplify `List` initialisation to get rid of repeating `New MyObject() With` as well as parameter names like `Value1`?
I need to create list of 50 objects, so a lot of repeated, potentially unnecessary code.

I use latest Visual Studio 2019 (16.2.3).

```
Public Class MyObject
    Public Property Value1 As Int32
    Public Property Value2 As Int32
End Class

Dim Test As New List(Of MyObject) From {
    New MyObject() With {.Value1 = 1, .Value2 = 1},
    New MyObject() With {.Value1 = 2, .Value2 = 2},
    New MyObject() With {.Value1 = 3, .Value2 = 3}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code shows how to add an extension method to the generic List type so that a collection initializer can be used to add objects of type T. The extension method enables you to use the shortened collection initializer syntax:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module MyExtensions_List

<Extension()>
Sub Add(ByVal list As List(Of MyObject), ByVal v1 As Integer, ByVal v2 As Integer)
    list.Add(New MyObject With {.Value1 = v1, .Value2 = v2})
End Sub

End Module
```

Now, you can simply use it as:

```
Dim list1 = New List(Of MyObject) From { {1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30} }
```

**Note:** The `Add` method can be an extension method as shown, or, it can be explicitly defined as a normal public method for the class you want to use (`MyObject` here)!

Ref: [collection-initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/) and [How to: Create an Add Extension Method Used by a Collection Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/how-to-create-an-add-extension-method-used-by-a-collection-initializer)

Comment: Works great. However thought that would be implemented as a part of language and/or .Net Framework itself. Is it the same in c#?

Comment: @Megrez7 : It is implemented as part of the language (both in VB.NET and C#). Any method or extension method called `Add` lets you use the syntax `From { {arg1, arg2, ...}, {...} }` when initializing an instance of its class. So for example a method like `Add(v1 As Integer, v2 As Integer, v3 As Integer)` allows you to do: `From { {1, 2, 3}, {6, 8, 4} }` (and so on).

Comment: @Megrez7 without Add method, this can be done by a little shorter code in c#: `var cats = new List<Cat>
{
    new Cat{ Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 },
    new Cat{ Name = "Whiskers", Age=2 }
};` but by defining the `Add` method, the final code is the most clean and short!