# Microsoft Visual Basic: how to initialize an array variable?

Tags: vba, initialization

I wrote a macro which performs certain operations on every instance of a specific set of Word Styles within a document.

To do so,  I created an array of names this way:

```
Dim mylist(4) As String
mylist(1) = "Heading 1" 
mylist(2) = "Heading 2" 
mylist(3) = "Heading 3" 
mylist(4) = "Caption"
```

I was unable to find any help pages (inside Office Help or at microsoft.com) which mentioned a shorter way to do so.  Is there any syntax that would let me simplify this into something like (pseudocode)

```
mylist(1:4) = ["Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3", "Caption"]
```

I'm looking for a general solution for one-line loading of an array, whether it's strings or numbers, when I don't want the entire collection of something like, say **all** styles in a document.

EDIT:  I ran across [Collection initialization syntax in Visual Basic 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85892/collection-initialization-syntax-in-visual-basic-2008?rq=1), which suggests the answer is "not until VB10" .  Any updates to that conclusion would be welcome.

Comment: We all secretly wish `VB` was more like `FORTRAN`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is close but a little different than: Dim mylist(4) As String

```
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit")
```

From: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/18225-initializing-arrays-single-statement.html

Comment: This will use more memory though. If you only want to use it for strings, stay with String type

Comment: I don't have any huge lists, so memory not a problem.  So long as it works for `Word` as well as `Excel` I should be OK.  I'll report back.

Comment: That link also suggested `Dim mylist() As String
mylist = Split("Heading 1,Heading 2,Caption", ",")` . Both options work fine, other than that I have to remember that these arrays' index starts at zero, not one.  Thanks!

Comment: Split("Ignore me,Heading 1, Heading 2 ...")  and you can pretend that the array is 1-based. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If memory is not a problem (so data type can be variant) this generates a base 1 array

```
Dim mylist As Variant
    mylist = [{"Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3", "Caption"}]
```