# Declare and Initialize String Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, initialization

This should work according to another stack overflow post but its not:

```
Dim arrWsNames As String() = {"Value1", "Value2"}
```

Can anyone let me know what is wrong?

Comment: Note: The curly braces syntax does NOT work inside VBA, it is designed for VB.NET. For your own sanity, do not get these two environments confused.

Comment: If you're using Excel (and you're content with a Variant array), you can use `Dim x() As Variant: x = [{"Value1", "Value2"}]`

Comment: For anyone who's looking at this comment, almost two years later (like me). It seems that VBA/Excel does NOT like the syntax `Dim x() As Variant: x = [{"Value1", "Value2"}]`  IF you are using variables... i.e. if `v1 = "Value1"; v2 = "Value2"`, then `x = [{v1, v2}]` will generate an error, whereas `x = [{"Value1", "Value2"}]` will not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual Basic: how to initialize an array variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828139/microsoft-visual-basic-how-to-initialize-an-array-variable)

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Try this:

```
' Variant array    
Dim myVariantArray As Variant
myVariantArray = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit")

' String array
Dim myStringArray() As String
myStringArray = Split("Cat,Dog,Rabbit", ",")
```

Comment: *technically* creates a variant array, not a string array. Of course the variant array *might* be an array of only strings, but this approach would also allow non-string data types: `myArray = Array("A", "B", 12345, "D"...)`

Comment: What about Dim myStringArray() As String ... myStringArray = Array( "Cat", "Dog" , "Rabbit").  Variants - yuck!

Comment: if you want to have it in one line, you can use the colon after the declaration:   ```Dim arrWsNames() As String: arrWsNames = Split("Value1,Value2", ",")```  The initialization from comment above does not work for me, because Array() creates an Array of Variants and not Strings

Comment: not a good answer as 1) it's a variant _containing_ an array and 2) variants are the slowest data type in VBA

Comment: @stifin and 3) VBA doesn't have String array initializer. But you can use Split for example.

Comment: This creates an array of variants inside of another variant.  To make matters worse, that variant, which is not an array, is named "myarray".  Not correct, not recommended.

Comment: This does not create an array but a variant. As variants can hold any kind of variable types (including arrays), it won't complain when you assign it an array in the second line, but it's bad style and may lead to all kind of confusion and other problems if you do so. I'd recommend to be clear and explicit and use *Dim myStringArray() As String*, as was previously suggested here.

Comment: @Andez: it would be great if `Dim a() As String ... a = Array(...)` worked, but it doesn't -- that's a Type mismatch error... Unfortunately there's no good way to do this in VBA.

Comment: @Nickolay Indeed...  Not sure where I tried that 4 years ago.  Although "matan justme" answer has been marked down - this is what I just did before reading down this.  His answer works.  You could have a global function to do this initialisation without using Variant as your defined type which makes more readable although  I would name the function StringArray.  That would be my chosen answer.

Comment: @Andez I don't know how I missed [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39277233/1026), it looks great indeed, thanks!

Comment: Make it Dim myarray() as Variant, and I'm with this answer. To those suggesting arrays of anything but Variants, be advised you can't use Array() to assign values to it. Only Variants work.

Answer (score 179):

In the specific case of a String array you could initialize the array using the [Split Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) as it returns a String array rather than a Variant array:

```
Dim arrWsNames() As String
arrWsNames = Split("Value1,Value2,Value3", ",")
```

This allows you to avoid using the Variant data type and preserve the desired type for arrWsNames.

Comment: This definitely makes passing it along to other functions cleaner; not to mention saving you memory...

Answer (score 33):

The problem here is that the length of your array is undefined, and this confuses VBA if the array is explicitly defined as a string.  Variants, however, seem to be able to resize as needed (because they hog a bunch of memory, and people generally avoid them for a bunch of reasons).

The following code works just fine, but it's a bit manual compared to some of the other languages out there:

```
Dim SomeArray(3) As String

SomeArray(0) = "Zero"
SomeArray(1) = "One"
SomeArray(2) = "Two"
SomeArray(3) = "Three"
```

Comment: so in the array declaration we don't define the size (4) but the highest index (3)? Do I understand it right?

Comment: @dpelisek, no. It's a mistake. In the example, the correct size should be 4.

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim myStringArray() As String
*code*
redim myStringArray(size_of_your_array)
```

Then you can do something static like this:

```
myStringArray = { item_1, item_2, ... }
```

Or something iterative like this:

```
Dim x
For x = 0 To size_of_your_array
    myStringArray(x) = data_source(x).Name
Next x
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Public Function _
CreateTextArrayFromSourceTexts(ParamArray SourceTexts() As Variant) As String()

    ReDim TargetTextArray(0 To UBound(SourceTexts)) As String
    
    For SourceTextsCellNumber = 0 To UBound(SourceTexts)
        TargetTextArray(SourceTextsCellNumber) = SourceTexts(SourceTextsCellNumber)
    Next SourceTextsCellNumber

    CreateTextArrayFromSourceTexts = TargetTextArray
End Function
```

**Example:**

```
Dim TT() As String
TT = CreateTextArrayFromSourceTexts("hi", "bye", "hi", "bcd", "bYe")
```

**Result:**

```
TT(0)="hi"
TT(1)="bye"
TT(2)="hi"
TT(3)="bcd"
TT(4)="bYe"
```

Enjoy!

**Edit:**
I removed the duplicatedtexts deleting feature and made the code smaller and easier to use.

Comment: This should be the answer - although there isn't any built in way to initialise, surely a global function as such to do this keeps the code readable and it doesn't inflict that your definition has to be a `variant`

Answer (score 3):

An only-what's-needed function that works just like array() but gives a string type.  You have to first dim the array as string, as shown below:

```
Sub UseStringArray()

    Dim sample() As String
    sample = StringArray("dog", "cat", "horse")

End Sub

Function StringArray(ParamArray ArgList())

    ReDim tempArray(UBound(ArgList)) As String
    For i = 0 To UBound(ArgList)
        tempArray(i) = ArgList(i)
    Next
    StringArray = tempArray

End Function
```

For more on converting array types see here: [How transform Variant to Double format and vice versa in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907468/how-transform-variant-to-double-format-and-vice-versa-in-vba)

Comment: I've been using VBA for more than 20 years and I didn't know ParamArray existed. You are a wizard, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

### A Functional Approach

Using the same solution as [@matan_justme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39277233/8309643) and [@mark_e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67931160/8309643), I think the structure can be cleaned up a bit.

Just as the built in function [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function) we can build our own custom function that uses a [`ParamArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays) to accept an array of items as the argument, and return a String Array.

By default, when assigning values to a String Array it will implicitly convert any non-String values into a String.

```vb
Public Function StringArray(ParamArray values() As Variant) As String()
    Dim temp() As String
    ReDim temp(LBound(values) To UBound(values))

    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(temp) To UBound(temp)
        temp(index) = values(index)
    Next
    StringArray = temp
End Function
```

### Reusability of this structure

The nice thing with this structure is that it can be applied to different data types with intuitive naming conventions. For instance, if we need an Array with `Long` values, we simply need to change every instance where `String` is located.

```vb
Public Function LongArray(ParamArray values() As Variant) As Long()
    Dim temp() As Long
    ReDim temp(LBound(values) To UBound(values))

    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(temp) To UBound(temp)
        temp(index) = values(index)
    Next
    LongArray = temp
End Function
```

Other Data Type examples could include:

- Single
- Double
- Date

The beauty is an error will be thrown when a value is not the correct data type and it can not be converted over, you will receive a `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch` error.

Answer (score -6):

Using

```
Dim myarray As Variant
```

works but

```
Dim myarray As String
```

doesn't so I sitck to Variant

Comment: That's because you should be adding parentheses at the end of myarray. The parentheses lets VBA know that it's an array. Dimming as a string makes it a String-only array.

Comment: you have to declare the bounderies of the array. Either a dynamic Array : `Dim MyArray() as String`, or a fixed size Array : `Dim MyArray(1 to 10) as String`.