# VBA - Proper method to initialize an array with string?

Tags: arrays, string, vba, initialization

I reviewed this question/answer here before writing this: [Declare and Initialize String Array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba?answertab=active#tab-top)

I am trying to understand the proper way to declare and initialize an array **WITHOUT** resorting to data type VARIANT.

This is my code, and it does work as it is:

```
Function MakeLegalFilename(legalname As String) As String

Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim x As Integer

MyArray = Array("<",">","?","@","%")

For x = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    legalname = Replace(legalname, MyArray(x), "", 1)
Next x

MakeLegalFilename = legalname

End Function
```

If I change "Variant" to "String," the code fails at `MyArray = Array(...` with a runtime error 13 type mismatch.

If I define the array size to match the number of characters in the string (5 total, but array starts at 0):

```
Dim MyArray(4) As String
MyArray = Array("<",">","?","@","%")
```

Now I get a compile error at `MyArray = Array(...` that says "Can't assign to array."

I know that I could declare the array this way and make it work (I tested it this way):

```
 MyArray(0) = "<"
 MyArray(1) = ">"
 MyArray(2) = "?"
 ...
 MyArray(4) = "%"
```

But if I am coding in a whole list of characters (say 20), then doing this is cumbersome, and plus, I would like to know why the other way doesn't work, since it suggests I have a fundamental misunderstanding.  In it's most basic form, my question really is, why doesn't this:

```
Dim MyArray(4) As String
MyArray = Array("<",">","?","@","%")
```

work?

Thank you.

Comment: review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba

Comment: @Sorceri  I did review that link and it is the link that I put at the top of my question.  I looked specifically at @Andez's comment in the top answer where he seems to indicate the `Dim MyArray() as String... MyArray = Array(...`, but that is still not working for me.  What am I missing?

Comment: Here is doc. to Array function : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675%28v=vs.60%29.aspx. It returns a Variant containing an array so it will work only with Variant.

Comment: @wackojacko1997  What dee said, needs to be variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array returns a Variant.

So you can't use it if you don't what a variant.

Split can split a string.

**Split Function**

***Description***

Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing a specified number of substrings.

**Syntax**

```
Split(expression[, delimiter[, limit[, compare]]])
```

Put comma delimited string into split containing your characters.

Comment: Thank you.  This answer addressed my misunderstanding that `Array()` returns a variant (somehow, I missed that point before now I'm clued in).  It also provides the a solution that most closely resembles the syntax I was trying to use.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use a helper function:

```
Dim MyArray() As String
MyArray = StrArray("<", ">", "?", "@", "%")

... 
Public Function StrArray(ParamArray args() As Variant) As String()
   Dim i As Long
   ReDim temp(UBound(args)) As String
   For i = 0 To UBound(args)
       temp(i) = args(i)
   Next
   StrArray = temp
End Function
```

Comment: @Alex K.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I would not have thought (and actually had not heard of) to use a helper function.  For my purposes, Serenity's answer helped me the most, but I certainly am grateful for your willingness to help me.  Thank you.

Comment: It's also useful to have helper function(s) that can convert an existing array to an array of a specific type. Eg. Convert Variant Array to String Array, or Byte Array to Long Array.

Answer (score 1):

To initialize static-size string array, use:

```
Dim MyArray(4) As String
MyArray(0) = "<"
MyArray(1) = ">"
MyArray(2) = "?"
MyArray(3) = "@"
MyArray(4) = "%"
```

To initialize dynamic-size string array, use:

```
Dim MyArray() As String
For i = 0 to 10
    Redim Preserve MyArray(i) 'increase the size 
    MyArray(i) = Char(64 + i)
Next
```

For further information, please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I like your suggested answer, especially the `Char(64 +i)` suggestion.  I accepted @Serenity's answer because it helped me understand my misconception most clearly, but I appreciate your help.  Thank you.