# Populate VBA Array with list of values in native code

Tags: vba, excel

Hoping there is a quick answer to this question....

I have an array and I want to populate it with a list of arguments.

```
Sub EasyArrayInput()
Dim myArr() as variant
myArr = ("string1", "string2", "string3")
End Sub
```

I am well aware of how to loop through and populate with a for/next or do/while, but it would be nice to be able to populate an array when the values wont change without using a hardcoded method.

```
Sub UsualMethodThatIDontWantToDo()
Dim myArr(1 to 3) as variant
myArr(1) =  "string1"
myArr(2) =  "string2"
myArr(3) =  "string3"
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to do it in a method similar to the first code snippet?  I would prefer to do it that way.  I apologize if this question has been asked/answered, but I'm not quite sure what the method I am asking about is called.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: Solution**

The code snippet below (from the link that chancea sent) will create an array that is a variant and exaclty what I wanted.

```
Sub EasyArrayInput()
Dim myArr() as variant
myArr = Array("string1", "string2", "string3")
End Sub
```

The next code snippet looks to be useful for if you only have strings and don't want to initialize a variant:

```
Sub EasyArrayInput()
Dim myArr() as String
myArr = Split("String1,String2,String3", ",")
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba

Comment: It's really not the same as that question.

Comment: Thanks chancea, I wasn't quite sure what I needed to look up but found the solution from your link.  I have added the solution in my question.  Really appreciate how quickly you were able to help!

Answer (score 10):

How about?

```
Sub EasyArrayInput()
    Dim myArr() As Variant

    myArr = Array("string1", "string2", "string3")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have some sort of numeric sequence, you can do something like this:

```
Dim myArray()
myArray = [TRANSPOSE(INDEX("string"&ROW(1:10),))]
```

but frankly I think a loop is clearer.

Comment: That would work and I would use it, but the code that I am writing will be transferred from workbook to workbook with different scopes/sheets.  I appreciate your help though!

Comment: I'm not sure I see the relevance, but OK.