# How to declare (initialize) 1-D and 2-D fixed-size array by enumerating the values?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to store constant name pairs in a 2-D array of strings. I can write:

```
Dim a(2, 1) As String     '0 to 2, and 0 to 1
a(0, 0) = "one"
a(0, 1) = "first"
a(1, 0) = "two"
a(1, 1) = "second"
a(2, 0) = "three"
a(2, 1) = "third"
```

But I think it would be more elegant and more extendable if I made VBA set the sizes of the array by looking at the instantly given content. I imagine something like this:

```
 Dim a({"one","first"}, _
       {"two","second"}, _
       {"three","third"}) as String
```

Then I realized I don't even know how to declare a 1-D array by instant enumeration (initialization).

Is this possible at all? If yes, how?

Is there official documentation out there covering this Q? ([This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264224.aspx) isn't.)

Comment: In VBA you cannot declare a variable and initialise it at the same time (other than its default value).

Comment: @Rory According to [another comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba#comment43045594_19369188) it is possible in one line: `Dim a() As String: a = Split("Value1,Value2", ",")` May this be applicable somehow for 2-D arrays?

Comment: @Greenberet Colon is just the synonym of the new line in VBA. That way you can write whole application in one line by replacing all new lines with colons.

Comment: Oh.. I think _I can see clearly now_. The basic A for my Q is a rather big NO then :)

Comment: No, there are always some work-arounds :)

Comment: Yes, the basic answer to the question you asked is no! :)

Answer (score 2):

The most reasonable way to make it more elegant is by creating the new function that creates 2D array based on the given string.

It could look like below:

```
Public Function create2DStringArray(ParamArray values() As Variant) As String()
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim strArray() As String
    Dim arraySize As Long
    Dim result() As String
    Dim iterator As Long
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    On Error Resume Next
    arraySize = UBound(values) - LBound(values) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0


    ReDim result(0 To arraySize - 1, 0 To 1)


    For Each varItem In values
        strArray = VBA.Split(varItem, ";")
        result(iterator, 0) = strArray(0)
        result(iterator, 1) = strArray(1)
        iterator = iterator + 1
    Next varItem


    create2DStringArray = result


End Function
```

Now, you could initialize your String array like that:

```
Dim a() As String
a = create2DStringArray("one;first", "two;second", "three;third")
```

---

Note that the function above has some limitations:

- it can take only up to 30 parameters,
- it doesn't work if any of the given string contains semicolon inside (unless you chose another separator, I used semicolon above).

Comment: Thanks. Explained eloquently

Comment: I am thinking of my answer

Comment: I focus on 2D arrays. As for 1D arrays your answer is correct. The only problem is that the array created by `Array` function is of `Variant` type and you cannot declare it as `String`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the nuance of array function

Answer (score 1):

For one dimensional Array

```
Sub aArray()

Dim myarray As Variant

myarray = Array("One", "Two", "Three")


For i = 0 To UBound(myarray, 1)

Debug.Print myarray(i)

Next


End Sub
```