# Assorted VBA array iteration woes

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim SourceList(0) As Workbook
    Dim PathList() As String
    Dim n As Integer
    PathList = Split("\data\WeaponInfo.csv", ",")

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Application.ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For n = 0 To Ubound(PathList)
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & PathList(n)
        Set SourceList(n) = ActiveWorkbook
        ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\HeroForge Anew 3.5 v7.4.0.1.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
    ActiveWindow.Visible = True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For n = 0 To UBound(SourceList)
        SourceList(n).Close
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

<s>The line `For n = 0 to PathList.GetUpperBound(0)` is throwing a "Compile Error (invalid qualifier) whenever I try to run this macro. Specifically it highlights `PathList` as being the problem.</s>

Also, if I cut out the loop and just have the contents run once (replacing the `PathList(n)` with `"\data\WeaponInfo.csv"`), it throws an "Object Variable or With block variable not set" error on the `SourceList(0) = ActiveWorkbook` line. What am I doing wrong?

I'm aware that the loop is currently pointless; it's futureproofing as I'm going to be using this macro to open multiple data references.

EDIT: Made changes suggested by @Jeremy below, now getting the "Object variable or With block variable not set" error on the `SourceList(n).Close` line.

EDIT2: Fixed the loop, again on the advice of @Jeremy, by changing `Dim SourceList(1) As Workbook` to `Dim SourceList(0) As Workbook`

Comment: Firstly you need to declare what TYPE n is

Comment: Added `dim n as Integer` to the declarations. No effect.

Comment: why are you splitting the pahtlist?

Comment: Because there's going to be multiple files listed in it eventually, I just haven't got that far yet.

Comment: It seems like it is VBA (as opposed to VB.Net) rather than scope per se which seems to be the problem. VBA as a programming language is actually identical to VB6 (the pre-Net version of Visual Basic). Reading up on the differences between VB6 and VB.Net could be a good way to become aware of some of the issues involved. Something like: http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/vb6vsvbnet.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. In VBA, the GetUpperBound method does not exist, it is for .NET only. Change it to Ubound function.
2. You may run into a problem with Sourcelist(0) = ActiveWorkbook. Use the Set keyword when assigning object references.
3. Source is not defined in your loop. ALWAYS put Option Explicit at the top of your code module to force you to declare your variables. It will save pain in the future.
4. What are you trying to do with splitting that string? you will just get one value, which is the string you are passing in.

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()  

       Dim SourceList(1) As Workbook
       Dim PathList() As String
       Dim n as Integer
       PathList = Split("\data\WeaponInfo.csv", ",")

       ThisWorkbook.Activate
       Application.ActiveWindow.Visible = False
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

       For n = 0 To Ubound(PathList)
           Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & PathList(n)
           Set SourceList(0) = ActiveWorkbook
       Next

       ActiveWindow.Visible = False

       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\HeroForge Anew 3.5 v7.4.0.1.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
       ActiveWindow.Visible = True

       For Each Source In SourceList
           Source.Close
       Next
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: The split is future proofing. There will be more sources being opened, that's why I'm using a loop. Apparently string arrays are tricky beasts though, and I had trouble initialising it properly. The split solution was suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba).

Comment: @TamCoton also there is a colon after SourceList which should go away.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Loop at the bottom is still giving me trouble though.

Comment: @TamCoton when you declare an array in VBA with length of 1, you are really creating an array with 2 elements, 0 and 1. You only have one item in your path list, so the 0th element has a reference to a work book, but element 1 is pointed at nothing, so it errors when you try to close it.

Comment: @TamCoton and just change the title of your question to "I don't understand VBA" :)

Comment: ...because that's really sensible design >_>

Comment: @TamCoton yes it is ridiculous, and works differently than most other languages out there. Here's a link on VB6/VBA array declarations. Unfortunately, documentation on the older stuff is harder and harder to find. http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-arrays