# loop through string array, error '9'

Tags: vba, excel

I can't figure our why I get error '9'. I declared the string array, then I would like to use the array values to set the sheet names. What I'm doing wrong?

```
Dim wsText() As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim wSum As Worksheet
Dim service As String
Dim supplier As String
Dim priceRange As String
Dim price As String
Dim Lrow As Integer, LastRow As Integer

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
Set wSum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Summary)

wsText = Array("<25K", "25K <100K", "100K <250K", "250K <500K", "500K <1M", "1M <5M", "5M <15M", "15M <30M", "30M <50M")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each element In wsText
        For i = 5 To LastRow
            For j = 13 To 47

                Lrow = wSum.UsedRange.Rows(wSum.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1

                service = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element.Value).Cells(i, 1).Text
                supplier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element.Value).Cells(4, j).Text
                priceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element.Value).Cells(2, 1).Text
                price = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element.Value).Cells(i, j).Text

                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 1) = service
                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 2) = supplier
                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 3) = priceRange
                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 4) = price
            Next j
        Next i
    Next element


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

for starters this part is wrong `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Summary)` here Summary is used as variable but cant see assignment to it in your code. That will throw error 9. if the sheet name itself is summary then use it inside double quotes like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")`.

Comment: ++ beat me to it :) Deleted my post

Comment: Thank you very much! I hate my self, that I can't look carefully on the code!

Comment: it happens to all of  us:)

Answer (score 1):

Declare your array as variant instead

e.g.

```
Dim wsText as variant
wsText = Array("<25K", "25K <100K", "100K <250K", "250K <500K", "500K <1M", "1M <5M", "5M <15M", "15M <30M", "30M <50M")
```

Reference:
[Declare and Initialize String Array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba)