# Determine Slope and Intercept using Dynamic Arrays VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Its been a while since I've used arrays in Excel VBA so please forgive me...

I'm trying to define a dynamic array based consecutive matching cells that are determined in a loop. I'm sure my syntax is wrong for defining the arrays I'm just not sure how. The difficulty is that my array consists of about 6 consecutive rows in 1 column, plus another cell in a different column. Any ideas?

```
Sub calib_range()
Dim instrument As Variant
Dim calibrator As Variant
Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("b2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = 4 To lastrow

If Cells(i, 4) Like "MPC*" Then
'enter loop to determine length of MPC* array
  For x = i + 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(x, 4) = Cells(x - 1, 4) Then
      Else
      x = x - 1
      Exit For
    End If
  Next x

  instrument = Array(Cells(i, 17), Range(Cells(i, 14), Cells(x, 14)))
  calibrator = Array(0, Range(Cells(i, 12), Cells(x, 12)))
  Slope = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(instrument, calibrator)
  Intercept = Application.WorksheetFunction.Intercept(instrument, calibrator)
  Cells(i, 22) = Slope
  Cells(i, 23) = Intercept
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You have `Cells(x, 4) = Cells(x - 1, 4) Then` and it goes straight to `Else` - are you missing code? Why have the `If` statement written like that?

Comment: @BruceWayne it can be that the values in the two cells are similar, thus it would not go to the else.

Comment: @Vityata - for sure - just curious why not set it up like `If Cells() <> Cells Then // x = x-1 // Exit For`.  (And sorry for the tangential question Kyle, I don't think this is part of the issue, just something I noticed.)

Comment: Same difference I suppose, just the way my mind was working when I wrote that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
  calibrator = Array(0, Range(Cells(i, 12), Cells(x, 12)))
```

You are not allowed to do so, because VBA thinks that in your array you get a 0 and a range. Thus, your array consists of two different types of valuse. Which is not what you need.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba) a little more about how to initialize arrays, it is well explained.

Edit:
Also on the previous line you simply make an array of ranges. What would work out for you is probably something like this:

```
Public Sub CheckArray()

    Dim my_array()   As Double

    ReDim my_array(6)
    my_array(0) = Cells(1, 17)
    my_array(1) = Cells(2, 17)
    my_array(2) = Cells(3, 17)
    my_array(3) = Cells(4, 17)
    my_array(4) = Cells(5, 17)
    my_array(5) = Cells(6, 17)
    my_array(6) = Cells(7, 17)


End Sub
```

Comment: How about `calibrator = Array(0, Range(Cells(i, 12).Value, Cells(x, 12).Value))`?

Comment: That would give a result, but the OP is trying to get a whole range (with multiple cells) + a zero into an array.