# Cannot assign variant array to typed array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, function

Can anyone explain why this VBA function terminates on the line that defines `MyArray` ?

```
Function FindEndPinyin2(Rge As Range) As Integer

Dim MyArray() As String

MyArray = Array("cat", "dog")

FindEndPinyin2 = 2

End Function
```

The function, simply exits and returns a #Value! error once it reaches the line `MyArray = Array(
"Cat", "Dog")`
  I realize this function doesn't do anything meaningful. It's a simplified example. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What language is this? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Is it Visual Basic?

Comment: Yes it's VBA. Sorry, I didn't mention that because I thought this was a VBA only area. I've now updated the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBA does not convert a `Variant Array` into a `Typed Array`. You should choose either and work with it.

```
Dim MyArray() As String ' <--- MyArray is a TYPED array
MyArray = Array("cat", "dog") ' <-- Type Mismatch
```

`Array(...)` is a VBA *function* that returns a `Variant Array`. As a result, you cannot do this assignment that converts a variant array into a typed array, even if the elements inside the Variant Array are all of the appropriate type (`String` in your case).

If you insist to do this conversion you will need a loop that fill the typed array element-by-element. Much simpler is to declare MyArray as a variant array, or just as a variant:

```
Dim MyArray
' Also works: Dim MyArray()
' Also works: Dim MyArray() As Variant

MyArray = Array("cat", "dog")
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: At least since Excel 2007, [it _is_ possible to assign the result of `Array()` to a typed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba). But not if the Variant array comes from elsewhere as an argument.