# Properly define string array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I usually use variants when I need an array:

```
Sub test()   'runs fine
    Dim s
    s = Array("a", "b", "c")
    Debug.Print s(1)
End Sub
```

Now I want performance for a specific case, so I thought I could save a few millisec by using a String array. How do I do that?

My try:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim s() As String
    s = Array("a", "b", "c")     'run time error 13: type mismatch
    Debug.Print s(1)
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Array() function returns a Variant containing an array.

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim s1 As Variant
    Dim s2() As String
    s1 = Array("a", "b", "c")
    s2 = Split("a,b,c", ",")

    Debug.Print VarType(s1) & " Array of variants"
    Debug.Print VarType(s2) & " Array of strings"
End Sub
```

Output:

```
8204 Array of variant
8200 Array of string
```

Comment: Excellent ! That exactly covers my case, and makes the array easier to code as a bonus. All I have to see now is if it's any faster :-)

Comment: Strangely, the 'pure string' version seems slower.