# Trouble importing compatibility mode workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, compatibility

I have a function that looks for open workbooks and pulls them into a master workbook.  It works just fine when I'm importing a workbook created with a modern version of office, but it doesn't seem to detect workbooks that open in compatibility mode.  Only the left 24 characters are constant for the workbook in question.

For a wide variety of reasons I've gone over in other posts downloading the workbook in question is not an option.

Here is the function.

```
Public Sub FindReport()

Debug.Print "Finding Report"
On Error GoTo Failed
Dim rName() As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim tWb As Workbook

rName(0) = "Case Detail"
rName(1) = "Disability_Claim_Status_"
'rName(2) = "placeholder"

For Each wb In Workbooks

'This line gives no output when I have the function try to find a workbook
'that has opened in compatibility mode
Debug.Print wb.Name
    If Left(wb.Name, 11) = rName(0) Then
        Set tWb = wb
        ImportReport tWb
        tWb.Close
        CaseFAS
        Exit For
    End If
    If Left(wb.Name, 24) = rName(1) Then
        Set tWb = wb
        ImportReport tWb
        tWb.Close
        'CaseFAS
        Exit For
    End If
    'If Left(wb.Name, 11) = rName(2) Then
    '    Set tWb = wb
    '    ImportReport tWb
    '    tWb.Close
    '    'CaseFAS
    '    Exit For
    'End If
Next wb
Failed:
End Sub
```

EDIT for clarification:

I had another version of this code that pulled in a specific worksheet that opens from a website, now that I need to expand it to handle another sheet I modified the declarations accordingly, and screwed up declaring the array.

Comment: Because of `On Error GoTo Failed` just jumping to `End Sub` if an error occurs you will not get notified! If you don't see the error message you don't know what's going on. Silencing error messages is a very bad idea, make sure you always get notified of errors (see [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)). Remove `On Error GoTo Failed` to see what errors you get in case of your compatibility workbooks.

Comment: turns out I somehow screwed up declaring the string array.......... compatibility mode wasn't an issue at all

Comment: I saw that but I thought the effect you figuring that out yourself would be more effective ^^ So you can write an answer for your own question, if you like.

Comment: I completely forgot i had that error statement in the code.  I put that in awhile ago when i had some debug stuff after the failed statement.  I took out the debug statements once I got it working, but never took out the error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Before assuming something complicated is the problem make sure you didn't screw up something basic!

Here is the answer to my question....

[Declare and Initialize String Array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba)