# WorksheetFunction.Match method Documentation: Example doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying the following example provided in the WorksheetFunction.Match method (URL:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match), but I getting a syntax error (line of code become red):

> Match returns the position of the matched value within lookup_array, not the value itself. For example, MATCH("b",{"a","b","c"},0) returns 2, the relative position of "b" within the array {"a","b","c"}.

What is wrong?

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim myVal As Double
    'Line below became red (syntax error)
    myVal = WorksheetFunction.MATCH("b",{"a","b","c"},0)
    'Line below works as expected
    myVal = WorksheetFunction.Match("b", Array("a", "b", "c"), 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Reed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369132/declare-and-initialize-string-array-in-vba

Comment: BTW, you can use square brackets to use Excel notation in VBA `myVal = WorksheetFunction.MATCH("b", [{"a","b","c"}], 0)` but I'd stick with `Array(...)` or `Evaluate(...)` instead.

Comment: Works with [ and ], see myVal = WorksheetFunction.Match("b", ["a","b","c"], 0)

Comment: {} is the user-interface syntax for an array, in VBA you should use the Array() function as already pointed out. You COULD use WorksheetFunction.Match("b", [{"a","b","c"}], 0) but, if you want efficiency you should avoid the [] syntax https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/

Comment: `Match` works in the way you try **only in a cell** as `=MATCH("b",{"a","b","c"},0)`. Only there `{"a","b","c"}` is interpreted as an array. In VBA you should `Evaluate` it, or use a real array: `WorksheetFunction.Match("b", ["a","b","c"], 0)` or `WorksheetFunction.Match("b", [{"a","b","c"}], 0)`, or `Dim arr, mtch` `arr = Array("a","b","c")` or `arr = Split("a,b,c",",")` and then `mtch = Application.Match("b", arr, 0)`. It is better to use `Application.Match`, instead. `WorksheetFunction.Match` will raise a fatal error, but `Application.Match` does not... Then, use `If Not IsError(mtch) then`

Comment: @SolarMike, using the code you provided, the red line alert disappear, but I got a run time errror 1004. But myVal = WorksheetFunction.Match("b", [{"a","b","c"}], 0) works...

Comment: @FaneDuru, I could not make the formula =MATCH("b",{"a","b","c"},0) work in a cell. Excel says there is a problem with this formula. I am using Windows 10 / Office 2019.

Comment: @SpectralInstance, thanks for pointed that "{} is the user-interface syntax for an array".

Comment: MATCH("b",{"a","b","c"},0) works fine in a cell, but then I am using a Mac.

Comment: Do you say that copying this formula `=MATCH("b",{"a","b","c"},0)` in a cell, **exactly as it is**, doesn't it work and raises an error? If so, this would be very strange...

Comment: @FaneDuru, thanks for the reply. No, it doesn't. Actually, I had to change the two commas between parameters for semicolons, since the pop window syntax require semicolons. When I paste it into a cell, it is pasted as a string (but the cell is in General format); when a paste it into the formula bar, I got an error. I tried the function with actual sheet ranges, and it worked as expected.

Comment: @FaneDuru, thanks for the reply. Now it works! I have to change all commas for semicolons. I had changed only the commas between parameters for semicolons, as the pop up window syntax required. Many thanks!

Comment: If you will place the formula using VBA, you can use it as it is (with standard list separator). I mean: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=MATCH(""b"",{""a"",""b"",""c""},0)"`. Excel will take care to adapt the regionalized list separator...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, you right! I tried it here, and the formula that VBA wrote into the activecell was the following: =MATCH("b";{"a"\"b"\"c"};0).

Comment: And does it work? I've  never seen an array using "\" as separator... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, it works, just as the formula I found before: either =MATCH("b";{"a"\"b"\"c"};0) or =MATCH("b";{"a";"b";"c"};0) works the same (they give me a number two).

Comment: Interesting... I learned something! What kind of localization do you use?

Comment: I am from Brazil.